# Is it possible to protect a Cognito Form with a CAPTCHA?

Tags: cognito-forms, spam-prevention, captcha

Is there any way to protect the form from spam-robots, i.e., choose a Cognito CAPTCHA?

Answer (score 1):

CAPTCHA is enabled automatically for all Cognito Forms.  You should not see it unless you are a robot.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/spam-prevention